# Best classifier in ROC Space

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining

I have been working on something and I made the following plot:
[image]

Since all the classifiers are below the random line, I read that we should/could "invert" them. I get that the classifier nearest to the top left is the best one. Here, how would I get the best classifier? Should I invert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't just "read", but try to understand the reason...

If a classifier is below the line, then it has a higher false positive rate than a false negative rate. In other words, the output of all your classifiers is **more often false than correct**.

Usually, **this indicates a configuration mistake**, and I would not recommend to hack this by treating the classifier as a 'liar'. Instead, find a fix the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that an AUC value below 0.5 does not automatically imply that the classifier output is inverted. AUC is an estimate of classifier performance, and like any estimate, it can suffer from bias. The negative bias is particularly prevalent in small-sample datasets and has been analyzed quite extensively in the field of bioinformatics. For example, take a look at the following paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17764577

Long story short: your predictor(s) might be truly random, but your estimate of their performance (AUC) is biased. If this is the case, there is no "best" predictor, since they are all as good as flipping a coin.